# Why is the 'type()' function not returning anything?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing some investigation of my Jupyter Notebook code in VS Code using this snippet:

```
print('type')
print(type([]))
```

I get back:

```
type
```

Weirdly, if I introduce an error after that snippet I get back:

```
type
<class 'list'>
```

I've tested the snippet in another cell and it works fine so there's something odd in my code. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I've done a little more testing and it looks like the error has to be introduced straight after the snippet. If I allow the code to run all the way through and then introduce the error then I get the original issue.

Comment: Does running the *exact posted snippet* produce the *exact posted output*? "snippet similar to this" sounds like a red flag that you didn't make a proper [mcve].

Comment: Yes it does - sorry. Should have been clearer. Edited the post.

Comment: `print(type([]))` does not return or output `type` in either Python 2 or Python 3. `type` is itself a type, and its representation should be `<class 'type'>'}`. If you are getting `<class 'list'>`, you must have done something like `type = list` previously.

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: @chepner: The `type` is (probably) coming from `print('type')`. `[]` is a list, so `type([])` is `list`, and `print(type([]))` is expected to print `<class 'list'>`.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a buffering issue. What happens if you do `print(type([]), flush=True)`

Comment: @Dunes - no change sadly. I can see that it does print out ```<class 'list'>``` but then it 'disappears'. @Daniil - any error I've tried 'fixes' the issue

Comment: Given what you've said in your edit, it sounds like the problem lies somewhere else in the code that you're are running, or how you've setup jupyter or visual code studio. I'd suggest running your code from the command line, to see if the problem persists. As it stands now, there is not enough information to reliably determine what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jossy I'm a developer on the VSCode Python extension. How exactly are you running this code? You mentioned notebook code. If you run it in the VSCode notebook interface it looks to me to correctly return back the expected value of:
`type
<class 'list'>`

Comment: @IanHuff - running it in a Jupyter Notebook tab. I'll send in an issue via VS Code.